# How to convert json array to json object in PostgreSQL?

Tags: postgresql, json

This is My Column cmt_json_value which has values which is of type json array.

```
[{"name": "Pending", "value": "PENDING"}, {"name": "Error", "value": "ERROR"},{"name":"Complete", "value":"COMPLETE"},{"name":"In-Progress", "value":"IN_PROGRESS"}]
```

I want to Write a Postgresql query to fetch name and value as column from table
configuration_matrix.

my existing query is:-

```
select cmt_json_value ->>'name' as name , cmt_json_value ->> 'value' as value
from configuration_matrix
where
cmt_category = 'LIST_OF_VALUES' and
cmt_key = 'JOB_STATUS'
order by cmt_json_value ->> 'name' asc;
```

Answer (score 2):

There is a special function for aggregation of name/value pairs: `json_object_agg`. Just place it inside a subquery or a `LATERAL` derived table.

```
select (
    select
      json_object_agg(j->>'name', j->>'value')
    from json_array_elements(cm.cmt_json_value) j
)
from configuration_matrix cm;
```

If you only want the data as columns you can just laterally join the JSON elements.

```
select
      j->>'name', j->>'value'
from configuration_matrix cm
cross join json_array_elements(cm.cmt_json_value) j
```

[**db<>fiddle**](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_14&fiddle=661e21abe280b5b0b293fd08908a94f7)

Note that using a set-returning function in the `SELECT` is [pretty weird and should be avoided](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23004157/14868997).

Comment: Your advise is, well, ill-advised. Craig's answer you are linking to is the state from 8 years ago. The behavior of set-returning functions in the `SELECT` list has been sanitized in Postgres 10. See: https://stackoverflow.com/a/39864815/939860

Comment: It's not the behaviour per se, I think both versions are weird syntax-wise, it just doesn't make sense to me to put a set function inside a list of scalar `SELECT` values. Single Responsibility is a thing in language design also. But everyone can do as they see fit, it's just my opinion. You yourself say *"A single set-returning function is OK (but still cleaner in the `FROM` list), but multiple in the same `SELECT` list is discouraged now. This was a useful feature before we had `LATERAL` joins. Now it's merely historical ballast."* and I think that applies even in the newer versions#

Comment: That, too, was before the behavior had been sanitized. The more relevant quote would be *"This ends the traditionally odd behavior."*

Answer (score 1):

```
select x.name, x.value 
from configuration_matrix cmt,
json_to_recordset(cmt.cmt_json_value) as x(name text, value text)
where
cmt.cmt_category = 'LIST_OF_VALUES' and
cmt.cmt_key = 'JOB_STATUS'
order by x.name
```

Even this work no need of sub queries.

Comment: Please combine your two answers into one answer, leaving the one that best answers your original question.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -2):

```
select object ->> 'name' as name , object ->> 'value' as value from
(select json_array_elements(cmt_json_value) as object
from configuration_matrix cmt
where
cmt.cmt_category = 'LIST_OF_VALUES' and
cmt.cmt_key = 'JOB_STATUS') as object
```

I tried this and its working.